# Filling a DataFrame based on conditions for both columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, heatmap

I have a dataframe (df_1) which contains coordinates and value data with no order that looks like this:

|  | x_grid | y_grid | n_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 204.0 | 32.0 | 45 |
| 1 | 204.0 | 33.0 | 32 |
| 2 | 204.0 | 34.0 | 94 |
| 3 | 204.0 | 35.0 | 92 |
| 4 | 204.0 | 36.0 | 84 |

I wanted to shape in into another dataframe (df_2) to be able to create a heatmap. So I created an empty dataframe where the column indexes are the x_grid values and row indexes are y_grid values.

Then in a for loop I tried I performed an operation where I tried if the row index is equal to x_grid value then change the column with the index of the y_grid value into the n_value.

Here is my code:

```
for i, row in enumerate(df_2.iterrows()):
    row_ind = index_list[i]

    for j, item in enumerate(df_1.iterrows()):
        x_ind = item[1].x_grid
    
        if row_ind == x_ind:
            col_ind = item[1].y_grid
            row[1].col_ind = item[1].n_value
```

What I run this loop I see that there are new values filling dataframe but it does not seem right. The coordinates and values in the second dataframe do not match with the first one.

Second dataframe (df_2) partially looks something like this:

|  | 0 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 27 | 0 |
| 195 | 0 | 0 | 32 | 36 |
| 196 | 0 | 65 | 0 | 0 |
| 197 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 |
| 198 | 0 | 73 | 58 | 0 |

Is it a better way to perform this? I would also appreciate any other methods to turn the initial dataframe into a heatmap.

Comment: I have put representative dataframes which show only a portion of the dataframes. so like the indexes are in range of 195-204 etc.

Comment: I ended up creating the columns based on the y_grid values one by one and merging them into a one dataframe to create the heatmap. This worked quite fast for me.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df_2 = df_1.pivot('x_grid', 'y_grid', 'n_value') \
           .reindex(index=pd.RangeIndex(0, df_1['y_grid'].max()+1),
                    columns=pd.RangeIndex(0, df_1['x_grid'].max()+1),
                    fill_value=0)
```

If you have duplicated values for the same (x, y), use `pivot_table`:

```
df_2 = df_1.pivot_table('n_value', 'x_grid', 'y_grid', aggfunc='mean') \
           .reindex(index=pd.RangeIndex(df_1['y_grid'].min(), df_1['y_grid'].max()+1),
                    columns=pd.RangeIndex(df_1['x_grid'].min(), df_1['x_grid'].max()+1))
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2022)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (1000, 3)),
                    columns=['x_grid', 'y_grid', 'n_value'])

df_2 = df_1.pivot_table('n_value', 'x_grid', 'y_grid', aggfunc='mean') \
           .reindex(index=pd.RangeIndex(df_1['y_grid'].min(), df_1['y_grid'].max()+1),
                    columns=pd.RangeIndex(df_1['x_grid'].min(), df_1['x_grid'].max()+1))

sns.heatmap(df_2, vmin=0, vmax=df_1['n_value'].max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this does not work for the case because I have multiple combinations containing the same x_grid and y_grid values? like 2,2 and 2,3 and 3,2?

Comment: You can use `pivot_table` instead and an aggregate function like `mean`. Do you want I update my answer with this code? (mean or max, min, first, last)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but I want to keep all the values. It would be great if you could show the code.